# Solar and wind powered

Tags: punctuation, hyphens

How to correctly write "Solar and wind powered" in a sentence? Are hyphens required?

Possible options:

1. Solar and wind powered
2. Solar- and wind-powered
3. Solar and wind-powered
4. Solar and windpowered

Answer (score 2):

Hyphens are optional, but if you do use them, use the style of (2), otherwise use spaces as in (1). A hyphen can stand for a common second element in all but the last word of a list, e.g.:

You may see a yield that is two-, three-, or fourfold.

[Hyphen (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen)